# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of XYZ bytes exhausted

Tags: php, apache

I'm wondering if anyone else has had a similar issue like this before.

A script for uploading and resizing images with PHP's imagecreatefromjpeg() function has been working fine right up to the server limits (listed below). But suddenly today after months of working correctly, I am getting this error when trying to upload images larger than 2MB (small than 2MB works fine!)

Server limits:

```
Max Post size: 10MB
original memory_limit in php.ini: 60MB
tested memory_limit in php.ini: 128MB
tested memory_limit in php.ini: 512MB
```

This is the type of error that I get:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 62914560 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 37772 bytes)
```

As mentioned above, I have tried temporarily increasing the php memory limit by using:

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "128M"); // Also tried 256M and 512M
```

Although the available memory appears to be increased based on the first number in the error message increasing (also checked via phpinfo()) unfortunately I still get an error.

What I find odd and if someone could also explain this to me that would be great:
The first value changes depending on what I set in PHP or in php.ini

```
Allowed memory size of 62914560 bytes exhausted
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted
```

but this bit NEVER changes??? Why??? Even if I try to upload a different image.

```
(tried to allocate 37772 bytes)
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe post your code, you may have a issue in your algorithm

Comment: Are you making sure no other requests are hitting the server for image resizing?

Comment: @BenR Hmm.. posting the code here might be tricky might appear all out of context but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @zaf Do you mean simultaneous requests for the same script? If yes, then the answer is: no in practice there is only 1 (in theory there could be multiple but at time of testing I was watching the logs and I was the only one on the site(limited access area))

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever had this issue when a permenant loop has been triggered, for example a while() where the condition never turns to false. Check for any loops in your code, it may necessarily not be anything to do with creating an image.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, it's code that has been running for months without issues that I am aware of, but I will take your advice and hunt for any possible offenders. Thanks for taking the time to leave your thoughts! :)